# How to call a excel vba function with respect to value in the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a Excel VBA function to perform certain action.  I wanted to call the function whenever I give any text in column A (row wise).

Say, if I give command1 in cell A1 then function `sample()` should be called.
Again if I give  command2 in cell A2 then function `sample()` should be called for second time and so on.

The same way until I am giving some value in the column A the function should be called again and again.

Is there any way to perform this action.

Comment: Like a `Worksheet_Change` event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to check if a cell in column A changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then 'only run when value in column A was changed
        MsgBox Target.Address & " was changed to " & Target.Value
        'run your function here
    End If

End Sub
```

`Target` is the cell that was changed.
But note that `Target` does not necessarily need to be a single cell. It can also be a whole range that changed eg. when a copy/paste was performed.